# Most recent resources for sphinx4

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

Is there a difference between the files from Github (https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4) and from the Maven repo de.sciss (https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=sphinx4+de.sciss)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, first is an official location, second is some random stuff posted by third-party guys. Unless you do not want to harm your security you'd better use software from authorized sources.